# Yolo V7 Custom Weight Works in Colab but not in Local Windows Machine

Tags: python, machine-learning, object-detection, yolo, yolov5

For my project I'm using **Yolo V7 for detecting some balls**.
I trained it with **8 batch size and 300 epochs** the detection was **perfect in Google Colab**
I tried same model in local machine (Gaming Laptop) it didn't detect and I had no errors showed in terminal.
I tried lowering confidence level and did as I can. Even I tried reinstall YoloV7 it gave me same problem.

My weight file and Testing Image is over here

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/11_O4Hu4KA-1xU9E3-LNXk1_Yq5OwGv_0?usp=sharing

**(This Model Worked / Performed Detecting Perfect in Google Colab,
I need to run locally for my project but its not detecting any objects)**

[image: Yolo][image: yolo]

**My specs**

1. i5 9th gen
2. Gtx 1650 4gb vram
3. 16gb Memory

Let me know how to fix this problem

Comment: I have same problem :-(.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your trained model with the image you provided and works fine.
[image: Inference result]

Try to follow these steps:

1. !git clone https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7.git
2. cd yolov7
3. run: ! python3 detect.py --source path to image --weights path to best.pt
4. check the result in yolov7/runs/detect/exp folder